# do we need to add provision at server end so that file downloading in browser can give facility for suspend and resume?

Tags: java, file, servlets, download

I have made a url by which user can download a zip file. I wanted to know if I need to add some sort of provision at server end so that client downloading the zip can provide support for suspend and resume.

Its implemented in java :

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // reads input file from an absolute path

  String filePath = "path to my zip file";

  File downloadFile = new File(filePath);
  FileInputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(downloadFile);

  // if you want to use a relative path to context root:
  String relativePath = getServletContext().getRealPath("");
  System.out.println("relativePath = " + relativePath);

  // obtains ServletContext
  ServletContext context = getServletContext();

  // gets MIME type of the file
  String mimeType = context.getMimeType(filePath);
  if (mimeType == null) {        
      // set to binary type if MIME mapping not found
      mimeType = "application/octet-stream";
  }
  System.out.println("MIME type: " + mimeType);

  // modifies response
  response.setContentType(mimeType);
  response.setContentLength((int) downloadFile.length());

  // forces download
  String headerKey = "Content-Disposition";
  String headerValue = String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"", downloadFile.getName());
  response.setHeader(headerKey, headerValue);

  // obtains response's output stream
  OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();

  byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
  int bytesRead = -1;

  while ((bytesRead = inStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
      outStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
  }

  inStream.close();
  outStream.close();   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to support suspend and resume, you'll need to add support for partial GETs, also referred to support for ranges or range headers.

RFC2616 (section 14.35) has the details on how to handle range requests.
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.35

Tomcat's default servlet has an implementation you can use as a starting point if you wish.
http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/tomcat/trunk/java/org/apache/catalina/servlets/DefaultServlet.java?view=annotate

Answer (score 0):

The application server has builtin support for this. Just make the file publicly available through server configuration. You're not clear on which server you're using, but if it were Tomcat, it'd be a matter of placing the folder with files inside Tomcat's `/webapps` folder like so:

```
apache-tomcat
 |-- bin
 |-- conf
 |-- lib
 |-- logs
 |-- temp
 |-- webapps
 |    `-- files
 |         `-- some.zip
 |-- work
 :
```

Or, if you can't move the folder, then add it as another `<Context>` to Tomcat's `/conf/server.xml` like so:

```xml
<Context docBase="/real/path/to/folder/with/files" path="/files" />
```

Either way, your files would be accessible directly by a HTTP URL without the need to homegrow a servlet.

```
http://localhost:8080/files/some.zip
```

If you still insist in homegrowing a servlet supporting HTTP range requests for that, then you may find [this basic example](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/02/fileservlet-supporting-resume-and.html) helpful.